# Teechart 9 Quickreport 5.05 XE5 installation

Tags: teechart, delphi-xe5, quickreports

I'm trying to install the TeeQR packages, and i'm afraid I might have no idea what I'm doing. I don't know which file I'm supposed to build and how, but it doesn't matter, because they all have errors that don't make sense to me.

The step-by-step instructions given by Steema led me to step number 15:

> "15. Build the project. You may find an error finding the correct runtime library for QuickReport. So you
>   should look for the dcp file that causes the problem at the requires list, remove it from the list and add
>   the correct one from your QuickReport installation folder, inside its bpl folder. Then, try to build it again."

No idea what that means. I just want to install two components that are suppused to be compatible with each other and with their version of delphi.

Tried to build DclTee9QR5D19 package:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] Tee9QR5D19.dpk(1): E2225 Never-build package 'Tee9QR5D19' must be recompiled
>
> [dcc32 Fatal Error] DclTee9QR5D19.dpk(35): E2202 Required package 'Tee9QR5D19' not found

Tried to build DclTQR919 package:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] TeeQR919.dpk(1): E2225 Never-build package 'TeeQR919' must be recompiled
>
> [dcc32 Fatal Error] DclTQR919.dpk(35): E2202 Required package 'TeeQR919' not found

Tried to build Tee9QR5D19 Package:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] QR5RunDXE5.dpk(1): E2225 Never-build package 'QR5RunDXE5' must be recompiled
>
> [dcc32 Fatal Error] Tee9QR5D19.dpk(35): E2202 Required package 'QR5RunDXE5' not found

Tried to build TeeQR919 package:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] TeeQR919.dpk(35): E2202 Required package 'QuickRpt' not found

Comment: You're going to need to be more clear. "For example: QR5RunDXE5 cannot be found (which is stupid)" has no meaning to us. Where are you seeing that error, and what is the **exact** error message you're getting? What is "something about 'never-build'" - again, what is the **exact error message** and how are you getting it? If you want help here, you need to be specific - posting "I get something like this stupid thing" isn't useful to us at all, and we can't see your screen to figure out what it is you're actually getting. Also, it helps to add paragraph breaks.

Comment: Alright, fair enought. Clearly I don't know what I'm doing, so I figured it would be pointless to elaborate on the things that I've tried, but I'll give it a shot:
Tried to build DclTee9QR5D19 package:
[dcc32 Fatal Error] Tee9QR5D19.dpk(1): E2225 Never-build package 'Tee9QR5D19' must be recompiled
[dcc32 Fatal Error] DclTee9QR5D19.dpk(35): E2202 Required package 'Tee9QR5D19' not found

Comment: Tried to build DclTQR919 package:
[dcc32 Fatal Error] TeeQR919.dpk(1): E2225 Never-build package 'TeeQR919' must be recompiled
[dcc32 Fatal Error] DclTQR919.dpk(35): E2202 Required package 'TeeQR919' not found

Comment: Tried to build Tee9QR5D19 Package:
[dcc32 Fatal Error] QR5RunDXE5.dpk(1): E2225 Never-build package 'QR5RunDXE5' must be recompiled
[dcc32 Fatal Error] Tee9QR5D19.dpk(35): E2202 Required package 'QR5RunDXE5' not found

Comment: Tried to build TeeQR919 package:
[dcc32 Fatal Error] TeeQR919.dpk(35): E2202 Required package 'QuickRpt' not found

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide that information there, where we can read it (and where it can be properly formatted) instead of in comments (where the formatting is an issue and people reading your question might not see it, and where it's not searchable by future readers here). :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform this operation you should be familiar with Delphi packages. Step 15 means that you may need to change the QuickReport package reference in the run-time TeeChart package for QuickReport (Tee9QR5D19.dpk) to the QuickReport version you have installed. In the example you post it is QR5RunDXE5.dcp. If that's not the QuickReport version you have installed you should  change that reference. Also notice that you need a QuickReport version installed before installing TQRChart packages. Once you get Tee9QR5D19.dpk compiling you should continue with the design-time package (DclTee9QR5D19.dpk) as explained in the instructions.

Comment: Only that's the problem. QR5RunDXE5 IS the quickreport version that I have installed.

Comment: BTW, What does the extension 'dcp' mean? I don't have that file in my system, even thought it's the correct version.

Comment: I guess "dcp" stands for something like "Delphi Compiled Package". You should have a QuickReport 5 for Delphi XE5 .dcp, probably at the QuickReport folder created in the Delphi XE5 installation folder ("C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0"). At the present moment I don't have this specific version installed but I have it for Delphi 2007, as an example, its path is "C:\Program Files\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\QuickRep\bpl". If you don't have the QuickReport packages properly installed you won't be able to compile and install TQRChart pacakges.

Comment: Only there's a new problem. While the file QR5RunXE5.dcp showed up out of nowhere in the folder simillar to: "C:\Program Files\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\QuickRep\bpl" that you suggested, and which I added to the library paths, - a new file is now claimed to be missing, and is required for building TeeQR919.pkg: quickrpt.dcp.  there is a pas file by that name in the QR installation folder, there is no QR package that will produce the required dcp file, and so I'm stuck again :(

Comment: @user2110866 remove that reference from the requires section in TeeQR919.dpk. This package corresponds to and old QuickReport standard version. You won't need it as you are already using QR5RunXE5.dcp. For more information please read the "QuickReport" article here: http://www.teechart.net/reference/articles/index.php